# Enumerate columns with same prefix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume we have the following simplified data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcd'),
                   'B':list('efgh'),
                   'Data_mean':[1,2,3,4],
                   'Data_std':[5,6,7,8],
                   'Data_corr':[9,10,11,12],
                   'Text_one':['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'barfoo'],
                   'Text_two':['bar', 'foo', 'barfoo', 'foobar'],
                   'Text_three':['bar', 'bar', 'barbar', 'foofoo']})

   A  B  Data_mean  Data_std  Data_corr Text_one Text_two Text_three
0  a  e          1         5          9      foo      bar        bar
1  b  f          2         6         10      bar      foo        bar
2  c  g          3         7         11   foobar   barfoo     barbar
3  d  h          4         8         12   barfoo   foobar     foofoo
```

I want to enumerate columns with the same prefix. In this case the prefixes are `Data, Text`. So **expected output** would be:

```
   A  B  Data_mean1  Data_std2  Data_corr3 Text_one1 Text_two2 Text_three3
0  a  e           1          5           9       foo       bar         bar
1  b  f           2          6          10       bar       foo         bar
2  c  g           3          7          11    foobar    barfoo      barbar
3  d  h           4          8          12    barfoo    foobar      foofoo
```

Note the enumerated columns.

---

**Attempted solution #1**:

```
def enumerate_cols(dataframe, prefix):
    cols = []
    num = 1
    for col in dataframe.columns:
        if col.startswith(prefix):
            cols.append(col + str(num))
            num += 1
        else:
            cols.append(col)

    return cols
```

```
enumerate_cols(df, 'Data')

['A',
 'B',
 'Data_mean1',
 'Data_std2',
 'Data_corr3',
 'Text_one',
 'Text_two',
 'Text_three']
```

**Attempted solution #2:**

```
[c+str(x+1) for x, c in enumerate([col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Data')])]
```

```
['Data_mean1', 'Data_std2', 'Data_corr3']
```

**Question**: Is there an easier solution to do this, I also looked at `df.filter(like='Data')` etc. But that looked also quite far fetched.

---

**XY problem**
Just be sure I didn't fall into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I want to use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), but the `stubnames` columns need to be suffixed by a number to be able to melt the dataframe.

As quoted from the docs:

> With stubnames [‘A’, ‘B’], this function expects to find one or more group of columns with format A-suffix1, A-suffix2,…, B-suffix1, B-suffix2,

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Data', 'Text'], i=['A', 'B'], j='grp', sep='_')
```

This returns an empty dataframe.

Comment: Is your problem limited to only two prefixes "Data" and "text" or should it generalise? Also, is A and B supposed to be an index?

Comment: Q1: Yes, the amount of prefixes will be small (mostly 2 or 3) so they don't have to be generalised. Q2: You can set them as index if you want, that doesnt matter for now. @cs95

Comment: May I ask a question , from the data structure level , adding that 1 to n at the end is redundant, so why you want to do so

Comment: Sure @WeNYoBen , but Im not sure if I understand you correctly, which part of the code you mean?

Comment: I mean the question , Just curious why you want to add the number count at the end

Comment: Ah oke, look at the bottom of my question, when I try: `pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Data', 'Text'], i=['A', 'B'], j='grp', sep='_')` This doesn't not work, since the `stubname columns` need to be suffixed with a number as the docs mention if I understand correctly. @WeNYoBen

Comment: @Erfan would you like to show what is your expected output for pd.wide_to_long ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195817/discussion-between-erfan-and-wenyoben).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to group columns with the same prefix, and establish a cumcount for them.

Since we need to handle column without a prefix separately, we will need to do this in two steps using `GroupBy.cumcount` and `np.where`:

```
cols = df.columns.str.split('_').str[0].to_series()

df.columns = np.where(
    cols.groupby(level=0).transform('count') > 1, 
    cols.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).radd(df.columns), 
    cols
)
```

```
df
   A  B  Data_mean1  Data_std2  Data_corr3 Text_one1 Text_two2 Text_three3
0  a  e           1          5           9       foo       bar         bar
1  b  f           2          6          10       bar       foo         bar
2  c  g           3          7          11    foobar    barfoo      barbar
3  d  h           4          8          12    barfoo    foobar      foofoo
```

---

A simpler solution would be to set columns you don't want to add a suffix to as the index. Then you can simply do

```
df.set_index(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
df.columns = (
    df.columns.str.split('_')
      .str[0]
      .to_series()
      .groupby(level=0)
      .cumcount()
      .add(1)
      .astype(str)
      .radd(df.columns))

df
     Data_mean1  Data_std2  Data_corr3 Text_one1 Text_two2 Text_three3
A B                                                                   
a e           1          5           9       foo       bar         bar
b f           2          6          10       bar       foo         bar
c g           3          7          11    foobar    barfoo      barbar
d h           4          8          12    barfoo    foobar      foofoo
```

Comment: Perfect! Great use of groupby, didn't even come up to me. Plus didn't know pandas had element-wise operator (`radd`). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a defaultdict to create a counter for each prefix.

```
from collections import defaultdict

prefix_starting_location = 2
columns = df.columns[prefix_starting_location:]
prefixes = set(col.split('_')[0] for col in columns)

new_cols = []
dd = defaultdict(int)
for col in columns:
    prefix = col.split('_')[0]
    dd[prefix] += 1
    new_cols.append(col + str(dd[prefix]))
df.columns = df.columns[:prefix_starting_location].tolist() + new_cols
>>> df
   A  B  Data_mean1  Data_std2  Data_corr3 Text_one1 Text_two2 Text_three3
0  a  e           1          5           9       foo       bar         bar
1  b  f           2          6          10       bar       foo         bar
2  c  g           3          7          11    foobar    barfoo      barbar
3  d  h           4          8          12    barfoo    foobar      foofoo
​
```

If the prefixes are known:

```
prefixes = ['Data', 'Text']
new_cols = []
dd = defaultdict(int)
for col in df.columns:
    prefix = col.split('_')[0]
    if prefix in prefixes:
        dd[prefix] += 1
        new_cols.append(col + str(dd[prefix]))
    else:
        new_cols.append(col)
```

If your split character `_` is not in any of your data fields:

```
new_cols = []
dd = defaultdict(int)
for col in df.columns:
    if '_' in col:
        prefix = col.split('_')[0]
        dd[prefix] += 1
        new_cols.append(col + str(dd[prefix]))
    else:
        new_cols.append(col)

df.columns = new_cols
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as well in this case, upvoted. Only problem would be that I dont know where the _prefix columns_ will start next time. Plus I fear that they might be mixed in the future (although the chance is really low), that's why I didnt mention that in my question.

Comment: The issue is how to differentiate data columns from prefix columns.  You would either need to know the prefix names, or else ensure that the split character (`_`) is not contained in any of your data columns, e.g. `some_data`.

Comment: Ye I agree, the point is that I'm dependent of an IT department. I've sent them extraction instruction, and until now everything went correct. Just try to be safe for the future.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `rename` such as:

```
l_word = ['Data','Text']
df = df.rename(columns={ col:col+str(i+1) 
                         for word in l_word 
                         for i, col in enumerate(df.filter(like=word))})
```

Answer (score 2):

Per our conversation, method `melt`

```
s=df.melt(['A','B']).assign(x=lambda x : x.groupby(x.variable.str.split('_').str[0]).cumcount(),y=lambda x : x.variable.str.split('_').str[0]) 

# after this the problem became a pivot problem 
pd.crosstab([s.A,s.B,s.x],columns=s.y,values=s.value,aggfunc='sum')
y      Data    Text
A B x              
a e 0     1     foo
    4     5     bar
    8     9     bar
b f 1     2     bar
    5     6     foo
    9    10     bar
c g 2     3  foobar
    6     7  barfoo
    10   11  barbar
d h 3     4  barfoo
    7     8  foobar
    11   12  foofoo
```

Comment: Thanks, for people who need a more "flexible" melt, this is the way to go.